# I need to get the average for every 3 records in one table and update column in separate table

Tags: mysql, sql, average

Table **Mytable1**

```
Id |  Actual

1  ! 10020

2  | 12203

3  | 12312 

4  | 12453

5  | 13211

6  | 12838

7  | 10l29
```

Using the following syntax:

```
 SELECT AVG(Actual), CEIL((@rank:=@rank+1)/3) AS rank FROM mytable1 Group BY rank;
```

Produces the following type of result:

```
| AVG(Actual) | rank |

+-------------+------+

|  12835.5455 |    1 |

|  12523.1818 |    2 |

|  12343.3636 |    3 |
```

I would like to take AVG(Actual) column and UPDATE a second existing table Mytable2

```
Id | Predict  | 

1  | 11133 

2  | 12312  

3  | 13221
```

I would like to get the following where the Actual value matches the ID as RANK

```
Id | Predict  | Actual

1  | 11133    | 12835.5455

2  | 12312    | 12523.1818 

3  | 13221    | 12343.3636
```

IMPORTANT REQUIREMENT

I need to set an offset much like the following syntax:

SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS Id , Mytable2.Actual FROM Mytable LIMIT 3 OFFSET 4);

PLEASE NOTE THE AVERAGE NUMBER ARE MADE UP IN EXAMPLES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can join your existing query in the `UPDATE` statement

```
UPDATE Table2 T2
JOIN (
   SELECT AVG(Actual) as AverageValue, 
       CEIL((@rank:=@rank+1)/3) AS rank 
   FROM Table1, (select @rank:=0) t 
   Group BY rank )T1
on T2.id = T1.rank
SET Actual = T1.AverageValue
```

Comment: THIS WORKS however I guess I missed one important requirement - FROM table2 LIMIT 3 OFFSET 4) - I need to skip a line and CEIL doesnt seem to allow any option for this..aaah